# Is it possible to add mod_ssl to an existing Apache server with yum?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, yum

I have an existing Apache 2.2.3 server running on Red Hat Enterprise in production.  Unfortunately, I now have a need to use https, and mod_ssl is not installed.  I was hoping I could do this in yum and avoid recompiling Apache.  But when I do:

yum install mod_ssl

I get a dependency error:

Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-22.el5_3.1 is needed by package 1:mod_ssl-2.2.3-22.el5_3.1.i386 (rhel-i386-server-5)

I guess I'm not sure how to get Apache recognized with that version number.  "yum upgrade httpd" finds nothing to upgrade. "yum clean all" doesn't help.  Anyone have any ideas?

If I am stuck with recompiling httpd, what's the best way to make sure I don't hose the server in the process?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I couldn't figure it out.  We went ahead and recompiled Apache with mod_ssl enabled and all is well now.

Answer (score 0):

Unless RedHat has done something really funny, mod_ssl was only separate with Apache 1.3.x. You should already have it installed with Apache 2.x. You probably just need to enable the module. (The [modssl website](http://www.modssl.org/) clearly says Apache 1.3)

If that's not the case, it appears you need to install the patches for RHSA-2009:1075-01. That version its asking for is from said update.

Comment: Thanks - mod_ssl is included with Apache 2, but isn't on this box for some reason.  Apparently I can recompile with --enable-ssl, I just hate to do that on prod.

I do have that Red Hat update installed.  So here's the maddening part:

    yum install httpd-2.2.3-22.el5_3.1
    Package matching httpd-2.2.3-22.el5_3.1.i386 already installed. 
    Checking for update.
    Nothing to do

But then:

    yum install mod_ssl-2.2.3-22.el5_3.1
    Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-22.el5_3.1 is needed by package 1:mod_ssl-2.2.3-22.el5_3.1.i386 (rhel-i386-server-5)

Yum seems to be confused.

Comment: @rich: wow, that looks messed up. I'd try using RPM directly... but I'd be hesitant of proceeding on a production box. Word of warning, I'm a Debian guy, so the answer may be immediately obvious to a RedHat expert.

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to install the openssl package.  Try looking into that.

Comment: hi skitzot, thanks, I did confirm that openssl is installed:

# openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008